# Class Binding, Array Syntax issue

Tags: vue.js

very new to Vue and seem to be getting on great apart from this little hicup and need abit of direction. I’m working on a hotels app for a travel website that displays hotels on a webpage, I want to toggle hotels based on it’s attributes/ratings via multiple checkboxes.

I’m trying to apply conditional classes based on boolean values within hotel object within my main array. This works when I’m applying the ternary expression within v-bind but when I turn this into a computed it no longer recognises the values within my hotels array. Code & [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattPremier/713zysp9/16/), any ideas?

WORKING EXAMPLE

```
<div v-if="" id="hotel-card" class="card" v-bind:class="[hotel.spa ? spaClass : '', hotel.family ? familyClass : '', twoStarClass]" v-for="hotel in filteredList">
    <img id="hotel-thumbnail" v-bind:src="hotel.img"/>

    <p class="hotel-loc">{{ hotel.loc }}</p>
    <h3 class="hotel-title">{{ hotel.title }}<h3>
    <p class="hotel-desc"> {{ hotel.desc }} </p>
      <p class="hotel-loc">{{ hotel.star }} Star</p>
   <a v-bind:href="hotel.link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-dark">From £{{hotel.price}}pp </button></a>
```

NOT WORKING

```
<div v-if="" id="hotel-card" class="card" v-bind:class="classObject" v-for="hotel in filteredList">
    <img id="hotel-thumbnail" v-bind:src="hotel.img"/>

    <p class="hotel-loc">{{ hotel.loc }}</p>
    <h3 class="hotel-title">{{ hotel.title }}<h3>
    <p class="hotel-desc"> {{ hotel.desc }} </p>
      <p class="hotel-loc">{{ hotel.star }} Star</p>
    <a v-bind:href="hotel.link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-dark">From £{{hotel.price}}pp </button></a>

     </div>

<script>
computed: {
 classObject: function () {
 return {
 'spa': hotel.spa,
'two-star': hotel.star,
'family': hotel.family,
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're iterating over `filterList`, you need to use a method instead of a computed property`

```
methods: {
    classObject: function (hotel) {
        return {
            'spa': hotel.spa,
            'two-star': hotel.star,
            'family': hotel.family
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the template

```
<div 
    v-for="hotel in filteredList"
    class="card" 
    v-bind:class="classObject(hotel)"
>
```

(I removed the `id` since that's going to result in multiple elements with the same id.)